# c++: статический массив - член класса в зависимости от константной переменной

Tags: c++, массивы, c++11, c++14

Подскажите, можно ли сделать вот так:

```
struct CMyData
{
    const int size = 100;
    int       array[size];
};
```

Просто не хочу в коде использовать во всяких `for` и т.п. *[magic numbers]*, а так будет наглядно - сразу понятно что это такое.

На текущую реализацию компилятор конечно ругается (иначе не спрашивал бы :))
А можно ли сделать корректный вариант?

Comment: `static const int size = 100;`

Comment: Какой смысл вы вкладываете в слово "статический"?  У вас в примере нет ничего статического.

Comment: а почему не сразу   int   array[100];?... Но все же лучший вариант это шаблонный класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не ясно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Тот факт, что константный член `size` у вас является *нестатическим* членом класса, говорит о том, что его значение может отличаться от одного объекта `CMyData` к другому. Конкретное значение `size` будет определяться конструкторами класса `CMyData`. В этом состоит ваш замысел? Если да, то использовать такое `size` для указания размера массива вы не сможете - такой `size` не является константным выражением.

Если же вы хотели, чтобы `size` всегда и во всех экземплярах `CMyData` было именно `100`, то нет никаких причин делать `size` нестатическим членом класса. Сделайте его `static const` или, лучше, `static constexpr` и все

```
struct CMyData
{
  static constexpr int size = 100;
  int array[size];
};
```

Comment: Ant, именно то, что вы написали я и хотел сделать. Я это и хотел сделать, огромное спасибо!

А чем `constexpr` отличается от `const`? (сейчас почитаю - раньше не использовал просто)

Comment: @Zhihar В данном контексте - ничем не отличается. А в общем `constexpr` приводит к созданию (если возможно) именно константы времени компиляции. `const` в общем случае такого эффекта не имеет: он объявляет просто "неизменяемый объект", который не обязательно является константой времени компиляции.